# Writing to large number of records take too much time using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm working on a project that just inserts relatively large number of records (250K records, just 2 columns) using Entity Framework code-first..

But it takes too much time to write all the records to the database (2~3 hrs)!

Is it because Entity framework is slow with large number or records or what ?

P.S.

Code snippet:

```
foreach (var t in myCollection)
{      
  Db.Words.Add(t);
  Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework is not a good fit for bulk operations. Even when doing the Context.SaveChanges() at the end (or every 100 records or something).

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{
    // This might speed up things a little aswell
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    // As might this (if applicable for your situation)
    context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
}
```

For best performance, you might want to use something close to the database like a stored procedure or if it has to be in code, use ADO.NET directly.

[SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx) might be exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `SqlBulkCopy`. I'd also like to point out the existence of the Sql Server [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) command.

Answer (score 2):

Add them all in a loop and then save once at the end

```
  foreach (var t in myCollection)
  {      
      Db.Words.Add(t);
  }

  Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: To clarify, it's better to store your changes and then write once than send write requests over and over again.

Comment: Also the OP has 250k records to insert. Doing a single `SaveChanges` on that many records will cause other issues. Probably better to batch them up in groups of 100/500 or use a proper bulk insert library.

Comment: Yeah and now one record has issues (too long of a string, non-nullable column being `null`, invalid relation) and all 250K of records fail. This is not _the_ solution, see duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, It speeded it up a bit more (~1000 record/sec instead of ~100 record/sec) on my machine, but this is still risky and relatively slow..

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by risky but Entity Framework will always perform poorly with bulk inserts.

Comment: I mean risky as per the case mentioned by @CodeCaster comment for example..